# How can the moisture of a peace of wood can be reduced to below 10% if the surrounding air humidity is over 50%

Tags: thermodynamics, evaporation, humidity

This question just came to my mind and I hope this is the right Stack Exchange to ask it.
How can the moisture of a peace of wood can be reduced to below 10% by storing it outside surrounded by air and covered from rain if the surrounding air humidity is over 50%? This is the regular process when you dry wood.

Comment: A glass of water would also dry out in less than 100% air humidity.

Comment: True, it is the same effect but how does it work?

Comment: Just standard vaporization.

Comment: Also the humidity of the air and the umidity of a piece of wood are different things (surely related depending on the context). There is no reason to compare the 10 and 50 values as per the title. True is that a dry environment makes drying of things faster.

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing incomparable quantities.

I believe - don’t know much about wood - 10% humidity in wood actually refers to 10% of its weight being ‘water’ that is non-structural. This is a case of absolute humidity. It’s measured by comparing the weight of wetter wood to the weight of the same piece of wood after it was dried (I think).

50% etc. Figures regarding air humidity don’t mean 50% of the air is water but rather refer to a relative definition of humidity. By convention, in the case of air, the percent-scale is defined as the ratio of the partial pressure of water vapour in the air relative to the pressure measured directly above a surface of water. It’s just a convention.

Hope this helps.

Best wishes!

Comment: I upvoted but it is the point I've also made. Tough, rel. umidity is the percentage of water vs the maximum amount possible at the given P,T.

Answer (score 2):

The wood will dry out as long as the relative humidity is less than 100%, assuming that the air and the wood have the same temperature. If the air has 100% humidity the wood wil no longer dry up. It may be that some moisture will take a very long time to escape. For example it could be trapped in places where it is very hard to escape or it could be bound by physisorption.

If you heat the wood it will even dry in air of 100% humidity.